# Passing options to gulp-jshint

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint, gulp

I'm using gulp to build my JavaScript. I want to run jshint on my files before I concat them, but I'm having trouble setting options. Am I doing this right?

```
var res = gulp.src(buildutil.produceFileGlob("./src", clientproperties))
            .pipe(exclude('**/test/**'))
            .pipe(jshint({ sub: false }}))
            .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
            .pipe(buildutil.jsmoduleConcat("myfile.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
            .pipe(closureCompiler(closureOptions))
            .pipe(header(buildutil.getBuildHeader()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

So all this works, and jshint is outputting its errors, but my sub:false flag does not seem to take effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`sub` option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#sub) is set to `false` by default — you need to set it to [`true` to have any effect](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#relaxing-options).

Otherwise, you are using it correctly.